# Flip PNG within SVG

Tags: css, html, image, animation, svg

I would like to flip the png file I have embedded in my inline SVG, as the containing elements cause it to be upside-down. I have tried editing the id="path104" element containing it with something like transform:rotate(180deg); but this takes it off screen.

Code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqBVjq

The PNG itself is embedded as a pattern in id="defs453".

```
<defs id="defs453">

    <pattern id="pattern-image-browser-filling" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">

      <image xlink:href="https://image.ibb.co/gtoOip/sdfgh.png" width="893.5" height="446.8"></image>

    </pattern>

  </defs>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your image: scale(1,-1) for a vertical flip. Then translate back translate(0,-446.8)

```html
<image transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-446.8)" xlink:href="image.ibb.co/gtoOip/sdfgh.png"; width="893.5" height="446.8"></image>
```